# Play! 2.5: Is there a way to bind actors only in Prod mode?

Tags: scala, playframework, module, guice

I bind actors at the start of my Play! application as following:

```
class Modules extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport with ScalaModule {

override def configure(): Unit = {
  bindActor[MainSupervisor](MainSupervisor.name)
}
```

I would like to deactivate `MainSupervisor` when not running in production. Today I pattern match on `Play.env` directly in the actor but I would like to separate the code from this.

Is there a way to not bind the actor when In Dev mode directly in the class `Modules`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to achieve this:

**Programmatically**

Inject Environment into the Module class and query its mode

Something like

```
class Modules(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration) 
      extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport with ScalaModule {

     override def configure(): Unit = {
         if (environment.mode == Mode.Prod) {
            bindActor[MainSupervisor](MainSupervisor.name)
         }
     }
```

**Configuration**

Specify a different configuration file for production mode

in prod.conf

```
include "application.conf"
play.modules.enabled += com.mycompany.MyModule
```

Answer (score 1):

You bind module in the configuration file, and you can use different configuration on the prod and dev, so you can just not bind the module on the dev configuration.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#programmatic-bindings

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration#specifying-an-alternate-configuration-file

Comment: upvoted since it is a solution but it forces me to maintain two Modules files so I accept @LiorH answer ;)